aoigram python запуск записи аудио по нажатию на кнопку
Может кто-нибудь знает - есть ли возможность в телеграм запускать запись аудио по нажатию inline button?
Понятно, что есть стандартная кнопка телеги для записи аудио/видео. Но может есть возможность запуска по кнопке, что даст возможность отложенного старта записи, отсутствия необходимости зажимать кнопку записи и т.п.
